# Snowflake SQL aggregate based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got 2 tables of User ID's and emails.
A user can change their email but keep the same user ID (row 2 and row 5 of USER_PLAYS table).
A user can also create a new user ID with an existing email (row 3 of USER_PLAYS table).
I want to be able to sum up the total plays for this user into a single row.
There is also another table with sales value that I would like to get the total sales.
I'm thinking somehow to create a unique ID that is the same across all these fields but not sure how to implement it.

Note that I've only shown 1 actual person but there are multiple more unique people in these tables.

I am using Snowflake as that is where the data is.

```
USER_PLAYS table:

|ROW|USER_ID    | EMAIL              |VIDEO_PLAYS|
|---|-----------|--------------------|-----------|
|1  | 1         |  ab@gmail.com      |    2      |
|2  | 1         |  cd@gmail.com      |    3      |
|3  | 3         |  cd@gmail.com      |    4      |
|4  | 4         |  cd@gmail.com      |    2      |
|5  | 4         |  ef@gmail.com      |    3      |

Sales Table:
|NET_SALE   | EMAIL       |
|-----------|-------------|
|5          | cd@gmail.com|
|10         | ef@gmail.com|

Desired Output:
|UNIQUE_ID  | PLAYS |NET_SALE|
|-----------|-------|--------|
| 1         |  14   |  15    |
```

Comment: How do you know that User IDs 1, 3, and 4 are from the same User?

Comment: We know that row 1 and 2 are the same user because they have the same USER_ID and we know that row 2,3,4 are all the same User because they have the same email. We know that row 4 and 5 are the same user because they have the same USER_ID. Therefore we can conclude that all rows are the same user. Logically I can work it out in my mind, I just don't know how to do this in code.

Comment: I don't have any good examples, but you should search on Transitive Closure using SQL.  That is essentially what you are looking for.  It seems like it should be easy, but it's not really.

Comment: So, logically ... you're saying that if the same user_id spans multiple emails, and emails that span multiple user_id, they reflect the same user.  There is transitive set logic involved here, but I believe this can be served generating 2 self-referencing table queries.

Comment: Solution below isn't necessarily optimized per se, but it does deliver the expected results.

Comment: Maybe create a CTE that assigns each row a "parent": the row with the lowest ordinal value where one identity property (USER_ID or EMAIL) is the _same_. Then create a recursive CTE that selects the original ID as a new ID value where the "parent" is null, or the parent's new ID when a parent exists.

Answer (score 0):

This may have opportunities for additional efficiencies, but I think this process works to get you the unique identifier across your user_id / email combinations.

For this process I added another column called COMMON_ID to the user_plays table. This joined with the NET_SALES table by email_id, can be aggregated to the sales against the COMMON_ID (see results below):

```
-- Create the test case
create
or replace table user_plays (
    user_id varchar not null,
    email varchar not null,
    video_plays integer not null,
    common_id integer default NULL
);
insert into
    user_plays
values
    (1, 'ab@gmail.com', 2, null),
    (1, 'cd@gmail.com', 3, null),
    (3, 'cd@gmail.com', 4, null),
    (4, 'cd@gmail.com', 2, null),
    (4, 'ef@gmail.com', 3, null),
    (5, 'jd@gmail.com', 10, null),
    (6, 'lk@gmail.com', 1, null),
    (6, 'zz@gmail.com', 2, null),
    (7, 'zz@gmail.com', 3, null);
create
    or replace table sales (net_sale integer, email varchar);
insert into
    sales
values
    (5, 'cd@gmail.com'),(10, 'ef@gmail.com');
    -- Test run
    -- Create view for User IDs with multiple emails
    create
    or replace view grp1 as (
        select
            user_id,
            count(*) as mult
        from
            user_plays
        group by
            user_id
        having
            count(*) > 1
    );
    -- Create view for Emails with multiple user IDs
    create
    or replace view grp2 as (
        select
            email,
            count(*) as mult
        from
            user_plays x
        group by
            email
        having
            count(*) > 1
    );
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
declare new_common_id integer;
counter integer;


Begin 
counter := 0;
new_common_id := 0;

-- Basline common_id to NULL
update
    user_plays
set
    common_id = NULL;
    
-- Mark all unique entries with a common_id = user_id
update
    user_plays
set
    common_id = user_id
where
    email not in (
        select
            distinct email
        from
            grp2
    )
    and user_id not in (
        select
            distinct user_id
        from
            grp1
    );    

-- Set a common_id to the lowest user_id value for each user_id with multiple emails
LOOP
select count(*) into :counter
from
    user_plays
where
    common_id is null;
if (counter = 0) then BREAK;
end if;
select
    min(user_id) into :new_common_id
from
    user_plays
where
    common_id is null;
-- first pass
update
    user_plays
set
    common_id = :new_common_id
where
    common_id is null and 
    (user_id = :new_common_id
    or email in (
        select
            email
        from
            user_plays
        where
            user_id = :new_common_id
    ));

END LOOP;

-- Update the chain where an account using a changed email created a new user_id to match up with prior group.

UPDATE user_plays vp
 set vp.common_id = vp2.common_id
 from (select user_id, min(common_id) as common_id from user_plays group by user_id) vp2
 where vp.user_id = vp2.user_id;

END;
$$;
-- See results
select
    *
from
    user_plays;
select
    x.common_id,
    vps.video_plays,
    sum(x.net_sale) as net_sale
from
    (
        select
            common_id,
            sum(video_plays) as video_plays
        from
            user_plays
        group by
            common_id
    ) vps,
    (
        select
            s.email,
            s.net_sale,
            max(up.common_id) as common_id
        from
            sales s,
            user_plays up
        where
            up.email = s.email
        group by
            s.email,
            s.net_sale
    ) x
where
    vps.common_id = x.common_id
group by
    x.common_id,
    vps.video_plays;
```

Common ID assignment Results:

```
USER_ID EMAIL           VIDEO_PLAYS COMMON_ID
1       ab@gmail.com    2           1
1       cd@gmail.com    3           1
3       cd@gmail.com    4           1
4       cd@gmail.com    2           1
4       ef@gmail.com    3           1
5       jd@gmail.com    10          5
6       lk@gmail.com    1           6
6       zz@gmail.com    2           6
7       zz@gmail.com    3           6
```

Final Results:

```
COMMON_ID   VIDEO_PLAYS NET_SALE
1           14          15
```